# Relating assets to each other in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This question has probably already be answered somewhere but I don't really know how to ask it. Sorry if this gets messy.  I'm building a new database for my works ICT assets which include assets, laptops and laptop trolleys. The database must include locations for the assets, for example 'Room01' or 'Trolley01'.

Is it possible to have the same item in two different tables that relate to each other, eg. a trolley that is both an asset and a location, where the trolley itself also has a location?

Comment: This question is not suited for Stack Overflow. Questions should be specific coding problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: this is a db relationship question but the answer is yes you just need to set the column as the fk to the pk of the other table.